# Compare results from column1 from column2 using SQL

Tags: sql, select, ssms

Backstory,
My company runs redundant call recording servers, each with a list of extensions.
We query these using SQL.  I can see there is a 20+ extension difference between the two servers.  These are columns that exist in the same table...so essentially I need to do the following:

Compare column1 data from column 2 'server1' in table system.name with column1 data from column 2 'server2' in table system.name and display those that **DO NOT** exist on both, but exist on one or the other.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example what you need?

Comment: @HoneyBadger For example, Column 1 will contain extensions (15551112222), Column 2 will be a server name (server1).  I need to compare server1 with server 2.  If 15551112222 exists on both...that's good.  If it only exists on one but not the other, I would like to display that result.

Comment: This question could really use some sample data. Even with your comment, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to do.

Comment: Try to use db link to query data from another db server.(for oracle only).

Comment: @JoeFarrell, I'm not sure how to provide more sample data...it's a simple question, I just can't get the syntax correct.  Column1 is extension data stored as VARCHAR(13).  Column 2 is server names stored as VARCHAR(60).  Extensions can exist on more than one server name.  I.E. correct configuration for an extension (15551112222) will be on BOTH server1 and server2.  (If I search for 15551112222, two results will show, one on server1, one on server2).  Sometimes this does not happen...and will only be on server2.  I need to identify those that are on one and not the other.

Comment: What's wrong with @uSeruSher's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can undertand from your question

Select column1 
from table1 a
where column2 = 'server1'
and not exists
(select *
from table1 b
where a.column1 = b.column1
and b.column2 = 'server2'
)
UNION

Select column1 
from table1 a
where column2 = 'server2'
and not exists
(select *
from table1 b
where a.column1 = b.column1
and b.column2 = 'server1'
)

Comment: It will really help me if you can just comment on what I did wrong before downvoting